# Publish to topic from AWS Lambda stop working

Tags: lambda, boto3, mqtt, iot

I have a Lambda function that has been working without issue for several months.  Starting a couple of days ago, now a publish to an MQTT client always times out.  Here's the publish code:

```
    client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-east-1')
    client.publish(topic= 'sdk/test/Python',qos=1,payload=mypayload)
```

From the log file:

*2020-12-18T13:57:35.652Z 6660d942-766d-419e-88d2-c09c11dd33cc Task timed out after 3.00 seconds*

The client is running on a raspberrypi.  I can publish to the topic from the Iot test console and the client running on the rpi that subscribed to the topic receives the test messages.

If I subscribe to the topic using the Iot test console, messages are NOT received

There's an inline policy for the lambda function for the publish:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I fix or debug this?  The 3 second timeout should be plenty long enough, so I haven't tried making it long.

Comment: Yesterday afternoon everything started working again--I changed nothing.  Quite frustrating, it took several hours to isolate the issue down to boto3 publish.  Since I didn't do anything to fix it, I don't know how to prevent it from occurring again.  So, I'll leave question unanswered for now.

Comment: Seems it had to be something going wrong on the server side, but I can't figure out why others didn't report similar issues.  Maybe there's a more common way to communicate between a lambda server and and IoT thing than to use the boto3 iod-data client publish?

Comment: Been running without issue since Dec 19, but today it stopped again.  I'm guessing it will just start working again.   If anyone has a clue on how to debug, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: This morning it started working again.

Comment: Today it stopped again.  Publish is just timing out in code running on Lambda.  How to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

I too had this issue and was able to resolve it by changing the Lambda runtime to use the latest Python version (3.8).

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  It's been quite a while send I set up the Lambda function, so I'll have to go back and review that.

Comment: I tried exporting the function to  a zip file, and reloading into a new lambda function using the same "role".  I used the same trigger definition and edited the "endpoint" in the Alexa Portal.  But, not triggering yet.  Next, I guess start from the beginning.

Comment: Hey!  It's working!  After I finally got the new lambda function set up correctly Now to see if it keeps working after a few weeks.   Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Should have mentioned, when I created a new function I also needed to change the name of the handler.  For some reason, it defaults to lambda_function.lambda_handler.  I just need to change the module name from lambda_function to lambda.  So, handler name is lambda.lambda_handler, not the default lambda_function.lambda_handler.  

So, the function was triggering, but failing since it couldn't find the named handler.  This has nothing to do with original problem, just getting a duplicate set up with a newer runtime (Python 3.8).  Any clue why changing the runtime would "fix" the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it may have something to do with the IoT endpoint that the boto3 package is using.

Comment: Hopefully it stays fixed this time!  If not, is there another way for the lambda function to communicate with the rpi that's running the backend for my smarthome stuff that might be more reliable?  I know I can use a custom skill and avoid using a lambda server altogether, and I have that too.  Just takes more words and response time is slightly longer.  But, I'm about ready to punt on the lambda server if it goes down yet again after a few weeks.

Comment: Have you considered running Greengrass on your Raspberry Pi? You can use it to run Lambda functions directly on the Pi. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-greengrass-run-aws-lambda-functions-on-connected-devices/

Comment: Is that an option for an Alexa SmartHome Skill?  I thought it required use of a Lambda server.

Comment: No, not directly related, but rather is an Internet of Things (IoT) solution that allows Lambda functions or Docker containers to run on the device.

Comment: I have an implementation that uses a custom skill.  It does not require use of lambda server (a good thing!).  But, I have to invoke the skill by including the skill name in the command.  Like "ask magic closet turn on back" versus "turn on back".  That's the ONLY reason I'm stuck with lambda.  Anyway, lambda server still working... Fingers crossed.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I was still having the same issue even after changing the python runtime to the latest version